# Elliptical Triangle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As per my proposal of a new geometric shape as outlined at: http://ellipticaltriangle.blogspot.com/

I tentatively think the figure could be reduced to something like this in polar coordinates:

r = sqrt(3)/sqrt(8-1 cos(3 theta))

This is a more desirable form as it's centered at the origin.

In Cartesian coordinates (shifted, not centered at the origin and rotated relative to the polar form), I came up:

y^2=(1/2-(sqrt(3-4(x-sqrt(3)/2)^2)-(x-sqrt(3)/2))/sqrt(3))^2

for 0 < x < sqrt(3)/2, combined with

y^2=1/2-x^2/3

for sqrt(3)/2 < x < sqrt(6)/2

However, in checking the perimeter of such, I am off by a small amount.

Anyone able to help me get to a clean equation for which I am seeking?

Comment: So, if I'm understanding your post correctly, you have a figure that is composed of three copies of part of an ellipse, and you are wanting the perimeter of this figure. It turns out that in general you can't work out the arc length of a part of an ellipse. When you write down the integral that represents the length, you find that you can't write down an antiderivative for what you're integrating. This actually created a whole field of study called "elliptic integrals".

Comment: Yes to the beginning but in checking the perimeter using WA I am off by a small amount compared to the Cartesian coordinate dual equations I derived.